# Add zoom to camera android

Tags: android, camera

I am new to android and currently working on an app which uses the camera API. I am having trouble with the implementation of Zoom function in the app. I am using Camera kit API to make the app and Camera-kit Api does not provide support for zoom controls. Please help me with the code required. I am unable to figure it out since a week. I need to implement Zoom to the camera Preview.

this is my Code.

```
public class MicroscopeAcitvity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    CameraView cameraView;
    ImageButton cameraTakePic;
    ImageButton buttonFlash;
    Camera mCamera; //= Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params;
    TextView T1,T2;
    int counter = 0;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_microscope_acitvity);

        cameraView = (CameraView) findViewById(R.id.camera);

        cameraTakePic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_take_picture);
        cameraTakePic.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonFlash = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_Flash);
        buttonFlash.setOnClickListener(this);

        T1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flash_text1);
        T1.setOnClickListener(this);
        //T1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        T2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flash_text2);
        T2.setOnClickListener(this);
        //T2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        cameraView.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {


            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) {
                super.onPictureTaken(picture);

                // Create a bitmap
                Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);
            }
        });



        cameraView.setFocus(CameraKit.Constants.FOCUS_TAP);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cameraView.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        cameraView.stop();
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id;
        id = v.getId();

        if(id == R.id.button_take_picture){
            cameraView.captureImage();
        }

        if(id == R.id.button_Flash){
           if(counter % 2 != 0){
               T1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               T2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               counter = counter+1;
           }
           else{
               T1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               T2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               counter = counter+1;
           }

        }

        if(id == R.id.flash_text1){
            T1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            T2.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            cameraView.setFlash(CameraKit.Constants.FLASH_ON);
        }

        if (id == R.id.flash_text2){
            T2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            T1.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            cameraView.setFlash(CameraKit.Constants.FLASH_OFF);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to zoom by pinch you have to implement a `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`

To set the zoom you simply have to change the camera parameters

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setZoom(zoomFactorValue);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

if you have some time you can code the rest yourself or look up how he did it

http://opencamera.sourceforge.net/

He uses pinch zoom on a surfaceview (but his code is not efficient and really ugly, very hard to understand on some points)